# File system read only on SSD with Arch Linux

Tags: linux

I would like to find a file system which is fast with SSD and especially on read time. This file system will not compress file and will make the file read only. I want to use it on my boot partition, so my kernel will have to be able to recognize it at the boot time. Moreover I'm using Arch Linux. Do you know a type of file system which can suit me without editing `/etc/fstab`?

Comment: ext4 is a mature file system and good enough for ssd. You can look for some fs benchmarks on http://phoronix.com/

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Bcache](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Bcache):

> Bcache allows one to use an SSD as a read/write cache (in write back
>   mode) or read cache (writethrough or writearound) for another
>   blockdevice (generally a rotating HDD or array).

The idea is to cache all data in an SSD, since the lifetime might be limited, the preferred usage is to use it as an read-only (write-through) cache.